# Xaml pass object with command

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

Lets say I have class that looks like this:

```
public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

User is part of the viewModel I use in my view, i try to update its properties like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding User.Name}"></TextBox>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding User.Age, mode=two-way, updatesourcetrigger = onpropertychanged}"></TextBox>
                        <Button Content="Save user" Command="{Binding SaveUserCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding User}" />
```

Here is the viewmodel:

```
public RelayCommand<User> SaveUserCommand { get; private set; }
        public MainViewModel()
        {          
           SaveUserCommand = new RelayCommand<User>(SaveUser);        
        }

        public void SaveUser(User user)
        {
            //logic for saving user
        }
```

I thought this would let me change the values in the textboxes and then pass user to the viewmodel. The problem is that nothing gets sent, `SaveUser()` gets triggred with null.

Can someone see what I am missing/missunderstanding?
Thank you!

EDit:

This is the property that represents my user in the view:

```
private User _user;
        public User User
        {
            get
            {
                return _user;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_user != value)
                {
                    _user = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("User");                   
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Bindings` on your `TextBox` controls need to be `Mode=TwoWay`. `TextBox` controls also only update the source value on `LostFocus` so you may want to change that with `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the `Binding` as well.

Your `ViewModel` also seems to be lacking a public property for `User`.

You need:

```
public User User {get;set;}
```

...according to your current `Binding` definitions.

I also can't see the definition of the ViewModel class, but it should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (or a base class should implement it).

**Edit:**

OP hadn't instantiated the `User` property.

Comment: Yes, you are right about that. I have both Mode=twoWay and UpdateSouurceTrigger=PropertyChanged enabled and it still does not pass the User-object to the VM.
I forgot to add them when I created this example. Thank you.

Comment: The VM implements INotifyPropertyChanged via ViewModelBase from MVVM-light

Comment: Has your User property actually been instantiated? ;)

Comment: Thank you toadflakz =) That was the part i missed. It works now!